# How to implement an ETL Process

Tags: etl

I would like to implement a synchronization between a source SQL base database and a target TripleStore.

However for matter of simplicity let say simply 2 databases. I wonder what approaches to use to have every change in the source database replicated in the target database. More specifically, I would like that each time some row changes in the source database that this can be seen by a process that will read the changes and populate the target database accordingly while applying some transformation in the middle.

> I have seen suggestion around the mechanism of notification that can
>   be available in the database, or building tables such that changes can
>   be tracked (meaning doing it manually) and have the process polling it
>   at different intervals, or the usage of Logs (change data capture,
>   etc...)

I'm seriously puzzle about all of this. I wonder if anyone could give some guidance and explanation about the different approaches with respect to my objective. Meaning: name of methods and where to look.

**My organization mostly uses: Postgres and Oracle database.**

**I have to take relational data and transform them in RDF so as to store them in a triplestore and keep that triplestore constantly synchronized with the data is the SQL Store.**

Please,

Many thanks

PS:

**A clarification between ETL and replication techniques as in Change Data capture, with respect to my overall objective would be appreciated.**

Again i need to make sense of the subject, know what are the methods, so i can further start digging for myself. So far i have understood that CDC is the new way to go.

Comment: What servers you plan to use would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: ETL processes usually transform the data (Extract, Transform, Load); what you describe sounds more like replication. Most commercially available (as well as a lot of open source) database management systems  have replication capabilities built in.

Comment: Isn't going from an SQL store to a RDf store, Extracting, transforming and loading ? even if continous ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't use replication and you need to use some kind of ETL process to actually extract, transform and load all changes to the destination database, you could use insert, update and delete triggers to fill a (manually created) audit table. Columns GeneratedId, TableName, RowId, Action (insert, update, delete) and a boolean value to determine if your ETL process has already processed this change. Use that table to get all the changed rows in your database and transport them to the destination database. Then delete the processed rows from the audit table so that it doesn't grow too big. How often you have to run the ETL process depends on the amount of changes occurring in the source database.

Comment: Given the context of the organization, i'm looking for a solution that assume that i can manipulate that database. that's why i have been interested lately in CDC.

Comment: without changing the source or destination database you would need some kind of indicator for changes (e.g. 'lastchange' field in each table). Otherwise you'd at least have to read all data from your source database which would, depending on the db size, probably take some time.

Comment: I have absolute control over the destination database, this is my realm. It just contain another representation of the data in the source database, slightly augmented and enrich according to the destination data model. However i have limited control over the source database. Rather than asking to manage that source database, which might be complicate because of the structure of my organization, i was thinking about some builtin solution. Also i'm not a SQL database admin. I know how to query it but little about how to administer it.

Comment: So let say i can use replication, what is it, and how does it differ from what you explained above ?

Comment: what do exist for postgre and what do exist for oracle ?

Comment: replication is a database feature (available for both postgres and oracle) that allows one database to replicate all changes to another database. The actual implementation depends on the database system. But usually replication means that both databases look the same. The replicated database is essentially a copy (and usually a readonly copy) that is kept up to date by the replication process. If your destination database differs from the source database, replication may not work for you.

Comment: if the source database is small and you don't need to be able to update your destination database in a short timeframe you could also consider loading the whole database each time. But that only works if the database really is small, say a few GB on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Btw the database are not that small and will definitively grow overtime.

Comment: So the solution sounds like having change data capture available. However it seems that is it available in oracle but not PostGre. Is there anything that can help to have that in PostGre. If i understood the all thing pretty well. CDC is having out of the box what you describe to do manually.

Comment: if there is one i don't know about it. Googling the topic ends up at a question in the postgres forum (from 2010) about that feature and no apparent solution.